# Initializing a dictionary w/ the values being (Of String, String[]) in VB

Tags: arrays, excel, vba, dictionary

I had the idea of creating an array of empty strings:

`Dim elements as String = {"%", "&", "@"}`

Then creating the dictionary as such:

`Dim dictionary = New Dictionary(Of String, elements)`

Finally looping through the range of the excel sheet from bottom up (lastindex specified as lenExcel from a function I have to get the last row in a sheet).

```
     for lenExcel To 0 step -1: 
        Dim faa = cDec(sheet.Range((lenExcel & num).ToString)
        If faa = 10.2 Then
           elements[0] = sheet.Range(lenExcel & value1).toString
           elements[1] = sheet.Range(lenExcel & value2).toString
           elements[2] = sheet.Range(lenExcel & value3).toString
           With Dictionary
              .Add Key:=faa, Item:=elements
           End With
           Rows(lenExcel).Delete
     Next
```

However, I think this will not work because the dictionary will hold a reference to the elements array. Hence, all of the array values contained within the dictionary for all keys would be the last values given to the elements array.
A possible solution would be to initialize a new array within the dictionary's parameters. That being said, I do not know VB and would appreciate some insight.

Thank you.

Comment: You certainly can make a `Dictionary(Of String, String())`.  As you note, you need to use caution to ensure that you don't put multiple references to the same array into the dictionary.  If you declare `Elements` within your `For` loop, you will get a new array each time through.

Comment: I solved the problem. The array is not passed by reference, but passed by value so the array can change, but the value of each key will not be updated with it. The way I was initializing my array was incorrect as well. I should've used ```Dim dictionary = CreateObject('Scripting.Dictionary')``` and initialized the array as a variant.

Comment: If you're using variants, then this is VBA and not VB.NET.

Comment: *"I solved the problem"*. Then please either add an answer and accept it or delete the question. Don't leave resolved questions unanswered. I'm sure I won't be the last person to open your question, read the whole thing and then read in your comment that the issue is resolved. If you respect the people whom you would like to volunteer their time to help you, don't waste that time.